# How to get an input value having different "name" value but same "id"

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server

I have a window.opener document with the below:

A table with 3-4 columns, I'm trying to pass the values of a row when it is selected (radio button)to the parent page.

However i can only seem to pass the selected value and other random "name" values that are not related to my selected choice.

To make things clear this is my table :

> Radio Button |  Serial Number | Agent | Country
>                     (o)                       123                     X           USA    
>                    (o)                       653                     Y          CA

If i select lets say the first row and press submit, i am only submitting the value of the radio button selected and then random values of Serial number, Agent, Country... 
 Below is a sample of the code im using on the child page:

```
var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtName");                                                        
txtName.value=$('input[name=serial]:checked').val();

var Agentname = window.opener.document.getElementById("Agentname");                                              
Agentname.value=$('input[name=Agentname]:eq(txtName.value)').attr('id');
```

Here is what im sending to the child page after searching:

```
<input type="radio" name="serial" value="'. $result[$i]['serial'].'">
<td>'. $result[$i]['serial'].'<input type="hidden" name="Agentname" id="'. $result[$i]['serial'].'" value="'. $result[$i]['name'] .'"></td>
<td>'. $result[$i]['name'] .'<input type="hidden" name="Agentname" id="'. $result[$i]['serial'].'" value="'. $result[$i]['name'] .'"></td>`
```

Comment: why dont you give them same name but different id? when u use mysql at that time name will be conside so i suggest that u take same name but diff. id!